# 404 on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic-security dist

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I am trying to install a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 today, with minimal install mode, and I'm having trouble with package installation. I've installed some basic things like gcc and git. On `sudo apt-get upgrade` I hit:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

and 3 other similar failures, then 4 of these

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_2.17.1-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

I can edit `etc/apt/sources.list` to remove the offending URL, but on a clean install, it seems wrong to have to do this.

I've done `sudo apt-get update` of course.

Any ideas of why this is failing?

Comment: It looks like the websites are down. If that is the case, wait a few hours and see if the problems is corrected.

Comment: I ended up editing `sources.list` and adding another mirror.

Comment: Please delete the question.